# Deploy a .NET Core App to Azure from Visual Studio Team services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, .net-core

I am building a .NET CORE RC2.0 app. I use Team Services to deploy to azure and the following guide: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

```
"Builddefinition\drop\website.zip' is not in a supported .zip format and therefore cannot be read."
```

How can the .zip format not be supported when doing exactly like the guide?

Comment: I've just followed the setup  myself and I can confirm that it works. Please place some screenshots here so I can help you determine where it's wrong.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue either. Can you share your build definition settings?

Comment: I gave up with RC2.0 and installed latest(1.0) instead. Seems Team Services is not ready for that yet. Restore and Build works fine locally, but in VSTS dotnet restore doesnt work. It tries to restore packages that are not compatible with dotnetcore.

Comment: The same behavior as this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139579/unable-to-build-default-asp-net-core-web-application-net-core-on-visual-studi?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. The problem was that the solution was created on a mac and therefor some important files were missing. So the solution was to create a new solution in VS on a PC.