# Unable to build default ASP.Net Core Web Application (.NET Core) on Visual Studio Team Services using Hosted Agent

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, project.json, dotnet-cli

Having created a new ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and checked this in to a Visual Studio Team Services git repository. I am using the release version of .Net Core and ASP.Net Core.

I am now trying to build this using the VSTS Build system using a build definition based on this guide: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure

However, the build fails on the `dotnet restore` step with the log shown below (first part not included, this is from where it starts to fail).

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to prep the current Hosted Agents in any way to get this working with the v1.0.0 release of ASP.Net Core?

```
2016-07-01T06:58:23.7437947Z log  : Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json...
2016-07-01T06:58:23.7457953Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bundlerminifier.core/index.json
2016-07-01T06:58:24.2167463Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bundlerminifier.core/index.json 469ms
2016-07-01T06:58:24.2188952Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bundlerminifier.core/2.0.238/bundlerminifier.core.2.0.238.nupkg
2016-07-01T06:58:24.4460947Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/bundlerminifier.core/2.0.238/bundlerminifier.core.2.0.238.nupkg 226ms
2016-07-01T06:58:24.4500936Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuglify/index.json
2016-07-01T06:58:24.7169172Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuglify/index.json 266ms
2016-07-01T06:58:24.7184197Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuglify/1.5.0/nuglify.1.5.0.nupkg
2016-07-01T06:58:24.9458237Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nuglify/1.5.0/nuglify.1.5.0.nupkg 226ms
2016-07-01T06:58:25.0165432Z log  : Installing NUglify 1.5.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:25.0175433Z log  : Installing BundlerMinifier.Core 2.0.238.
2016-07-01T06:58:26.3365438Z log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json...
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5785417Z error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5815442Z error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5815442Z error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5828217Z error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5835753Z error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5845450Z log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json...
2016-07-01T06:58:27.5855447Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/index.json
2016-07-01T06:58:27.8429648Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/index.json 257ms
2016-07-01T06:58:27.8452904Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/1.0.0-preview2-final/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools.1.0.0-preview2-final.nupkg
2016-07-01T06:58:28.0722938Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools/1.0.0-preview2-final/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.tools.1.0.0-preview2-final.nupkg 226ms
2016-07-01T06:58:28.1392401Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel/index.json
2016-07-01T06:58:28.4376727Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel/index.json 298ms
2016-07-01T06:58:28.4406725Z info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel/1.0.0-rc3-003121/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel.1.0.0-rc3-003121.nupkg
2016-07-01T06:58:28.6676393Z info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel/1.0.0-rc3-003121/microsoft.dotnet.projectmodel.1.0.0-rc3-003121.nupkg 227ms
2016-07-01T06:58:28.6946386Z log  : Installing Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121.
2016-07-01T06:58:28.6956390Z log  : Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.3480344Z error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.3500341Z error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.3500341Z error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.3510431Z error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7120347Z error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7130338Z error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7140347Z error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7140347Z error: Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7140347Z error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7150344Z error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7150344Z error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7160344Z error: Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7160344Z error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7160344Z error:   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7174190Z error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7174190Z info : Committing restore...
2016-07-01T06:58:32.7210345Z log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.lock.json
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9154998Z log  : C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9174999Z log  : Restore failed in 44621ms.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9274991Z NuGet Config files used:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9294993Z Errors in C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9294993Z     Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9305008Z     Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9305008Z       - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9315007Z       - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9315007Z     One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9325003Z     Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel 1.0.0-rc3-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9325003Z       - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9325003Z       - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9335002Z     One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9335002Z     Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9345003Z       - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9345003Z       - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9355002Z     Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.0 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9355002Z       - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9355002Z       - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9365007Z     Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9365007Z     Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils 1.0.0-preview2-003121 supports:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9374999Z       - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9374999Z       - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9385006Z     One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9385006Z     C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9385006Z     C:\ProgramData\nuget\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9395005Z Feeds used:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9395005Z     https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9405006Z     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9514998Z Installed:
2016-07-01T06:58:32.9525024Z     159 package(s) to C:\a\1\s\src\FjordTours.BasicApp\project.json
```

The global.json (as created by the ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) template):

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

The project.json (as created by the ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) template):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I did follow those instruction but using the Hosted Agent alternative. We would like to use Hosted Agents as we currently have no option to use on-premise build agents.

Comment: On the general tab, what "Demand" did you add?

Comment: I did not add any Demand. What should I add? Since I am using the Hosted Agents I can't seem to be able to add any demands. Also, according to the doc mentioned above the demand only needs to be added to custom build agents but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This looks like the build system is using an older version of .Net Core SDK. Can you upgrade that to 1.0?

Comment: As of 13 July 2016, The VSTS hosted build agents have been updated to include ".NET Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling". See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/13/july-hosted-build-pool-image-updates/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace "tools" section in your project.json like this:

```
    "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.1.258",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81",
        "netstandard1.6"
      ]
    }
  },
```

some packages needs to import `netstandard1.6`
but `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` needs `netstandard1.6` and `portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81`

Comment: Great, that helped me get rid of most of the errors. But I still get the same errors for other packages, some of them not explicitly stated in the `project.json`, such as `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader`. How can I find out how to resolve those issues?

Comment: I too had the error with Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Loader but in my case replacing the tools section as described in neodim's answer solved it for me.

Comment: As a side node you should no longer need imports with preview2. Try cleaning your cache(s) (`nuget.exe locals -clear all`)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with `dotnet restore` using the hosted build agent in VSTS.  Based on the comment from @svick , I ran `dotnet --version` to check what is installed on the hosted agent.  As of today, it is still `1.0.0-preview1-002702` and not the referenced version of `1.0.0-preview2-003121`.

```
2016-07-04T06:17:47.5047693Z ##[warning]File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
2016-07-04T06:17:47.5057787Z Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
2016-07-04T06:17:47.5057787Z dotnet --version
2016-07-04T06:17:47.5067748Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2016-07-04T06:17:47.5067748Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
2016-07-04T06:17:48.9679166Z 1.0.0-preview1-002702
```

The official software for the hosted build agents can be found at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/hosted-pool  . In particular, notice it still shows `Visual Studio 2015 Update 2`.  Hopefully, this gets updated soon.

Comment: As of 13 July 2016, The VSTS hosted build agents have been updated to include ".NET Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling".  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/13/july-hosted-build-pool-image-updates/